# Store Range Offset as Variable User Defined Text to Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub and as part of it I'm converting data from text to columns and I would like to specify the location where the conversion goes.  The idea is the user selects the cell to start at, the sub goes through it's process and converts data from text to columns starting with the activated cell column.  I would like to ideally save the offset location as a variable so that I can further manipulate it throughout the remainder of the sub.  My data is "_" delimited.

```
currentCell = ActiveCell.Address
Dim newLocation As Range
newLocation = ActiveCell.Offset(0,5)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.TextToColumns _
    Destination:=Range(newLocation), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
    Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, _
    Space:=False, _
    Other:=True, _
    OtherChar:="_"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **Set** and fix the **Destination** line:

```
Sub dural()
    currentCell = ActiveCell.Address
    Dim newLocation As Range
    Set newLocation = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=newLocation, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:="_"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. That works.  Now I understand why when I had Destination:=Range(newLocation) I was being thrown a Run-Time Error Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failied